# Cannot insert Sheets chart to presentation via Google Slides API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api

I am trying to insert chart to Google Slides presentation using [`CreateSheetsChartRequest`](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createsheetschartrequest).

Request fails with error:

> Execution failed: GoogleJsonResponseException: Invalid value at 'requests[0].create_sheets_chart.chart_id' (TYPE_INT32), "u1935822328711"

Sample code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var chartSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

// get chart id via Sheets API
// returns string like 'u1935822328711'
var chartId = chartSheet.getCharts()[0].getId();

var slidesReqs = [];

slidesReqs.push({
  createSheetsChart: {
    objectId: 'someSlideChartId',
    elementProperties: {
      pageObjectId: slideId,
      size: {
        width: {
          magnitude: (7/9)*900,
          unit: 'PT'
        },
        height: {
          magnitude: (7/9)*560,
          unit: 'PT'
        }
      },
      transform: {
        scaleX: 1,
        scaleY: 1,
        translateX: 100000,
        translateY: 100000,
        unit: 'EMU'
      }
    },
    spreadsheetId: ss.getId(),
    chartId: chartId,
    linkingMode: 'NOT_LINKED_IMAGE'
  }
});

// throws error
// Execution failed: GoogleJsonResponseException: Invalid value at 'requests[0].create_sheets_chart.chart_id' (TYPE_INT32), "u1935822328711"
Slides.Presentations.batchUpdate({'requests': slidesReqs}, presentationFileId);
```

I see that [`CreateSheetsChartRequest`](https://developers.google.com/slides/api/reference/rest/v1/presentations/request#createsheetschartrequest) expects field `chartId` to be integer, but Google Sheets API returns string like "u1935822328711" for chart id.

How do I get Google Sheets chart inserted to slide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Short answer

Use [`getChartId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getchartid) instead of `getId()`.

### Explanation

[`EmbeddedChart.getId()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20170806182056/https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getid) returns an ID that is only useful in the context of `UiApp`, a deprecated service for building component-based UIs.

However, as of today, there is now a method on the `EmbeddedChart` class called **[`getChartId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getchartid)** that returns *a unique, stable integer* identifying the chart.

If you change the one line in your code to

```
var chartId = chartSheet.getCharts()[0].getChartId();
```

your `CreateSheetsChartRequest` should now work.

Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79784012#comment2

Comment: Thank you for this information. This is very helpful for me. The simple document is [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/sheets-chart#getChartId()). I couldn't understand the usage. But from your question and answer, I could know the detail about this. Thank you.

Comment: @Tanaike before inserting to Slides we need to get chart id from Sheet's  `EmbeddedChart`, that's where hidden method lives. Method you provided link to can be used *after* inserting to Slides.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I would like to take advantage of this in my applications.